# Bullet graph in browser - alternative to d3.js? (with good browser support)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I want to implement [d3.js bullet graph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bullet.html)
in my applications but its not supported in IE (< 9).

Is there any other JavaScript libraries for implementing bullet graphs?

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Sparklines also has a bullet graph: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

The documentation states that the library has been tested on "Firefox 2+, Safari 3+, Opera 9, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8".

Comment: Thanks Charl Botha.  i have seen jQuery Sparklines, but its not much interactive. i Want a graph same as d3.js bullet graph..

Answer (score 0):

You can try JQBulletGraph, which is part of the JQGauges product set. It is compatible across all modern browsers (IE 6+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari).

Here is a link with examples: http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/BulletGraph/LiveData

Disclaimer: I work for JQChart.

Best Regards,
Maxim Milev